# Advent Bounties 2020

Tags: discussion

Not sure if Advent seems early or late to you (or you're in a liturgical tradition that doesn't celebrate Advent (or you have no liturgical tradition)) but Advent's the season of the year leading up to Christmas wherein we reflect on the second coming, be penitent all the while getting ready for the celebration of Christmas.

On Christianity.SE we've had a "fun" tradition of rewarding the best answers of the year (or sometimes inspiring more good answers) by offering bounties each week of advent to some stellar Q & A.

This year, like every other year, there's no theme, just go find answers you like, put a bounty on the question, award the bounty within the week and make someone's day! If I were to pick a theme, just to help, I'd go with evangelization and spreading the Gospel and avoid anything in the Exodus 10-11 area, we don't need any more of that this year!

Post your bounties below in the Answer Section, one post per week for the 4 weeks of Advent.

Answer (score 1):

## First Week of Advent

November 29th to December 6th, 2020

- [Does street preaching actually work?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33661/4) - Peter Turner nominated this because He wanted to know if it's really worth it to go out with an "End is Near" sign, or if everyone already knows.
- 
- 
- 

Answer (score 1):

## Second Week of Advent

December 6th to December 13th 2020

- [What is an overview of Christian viewpoints on discerning between genuine Holy Spirit manifestations versus counterfeits (e.g. Kundalini awakening)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79925/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-viewpoints-on-discerning-between-genuine-holy-s) **Spirit Realm Investigator** is looking for a **canonical answer**.
- [What is the biblical basis for interpreting “born again”, “baptized in the Holy Spirit” and “filled with the Holy Spirit” as different experiences?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79959/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-interpreting-born-again-baptized-in-the-holy). **Spirit Realm Investigator** wants to draw more attention to this question
- [In evangelicalism, how are Christians free from sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11830/in-evangelicalism-how-are-christians-free-from-sin)  **Tiago Martins Peres 李大仁** wants to reward an existing answer
- [Why are there Sybils and Prophetesses in the Sistine Chapel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/751/why-are-there-sybils-and-prophetesses-in-the-sistine-chapel) **Peter Turner** really wants to know what those ladies represented, maybe they sneakily pointed to Christ, like many pagans were known to have done without realizing it.
- 
- 

Answer (score 1):

## Third Week of Advent

December 13th to December 20th 2020

- [Why is Christmas on December 25th?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/why-is-christmas-on-december-25th)
- [Did St. Thomas come to India](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20096/did-st-thomas-come-to-india)?  There's gotta be more to the story!
- 
- 

Answer (score 0):

## Fourth Week of Advent

December 20th to December 24th 2020

- 
- 
- 
- 